# Mybatis mapper for PROC call with multiple IN and OUT parameters

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am new to mybatis and stuck with calling a stored procedure. My procedure has 4 parameters

1. IN - searchQuery of type String
2. OUT - returnCode of type int
3. OUT - returnMsg of type String
4. OUT - prodList of type Array of custom STRUCT

How should I model my parameter and result object, provide the mappers?